# Error 1054 in UPDATE command in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I'm getting the 1054 error everytime I try to update a table. Here the transcription in the Command Line Client:

```
mysql>UPDATE Produtos SET prdNome = 'TESTE' WHERE prdCodigo=3;
      ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'prdCodigo' in 'where clause'
```

This error occurs when the value used in the where clause exists in the table.
If I enter a non existing value, there are no errors, like this:

```
mysql>UPDATE Produtos SET prdNome = 'TESTE' WHERE prdCodigo=0;
      Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
      Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

What I'm doing wrong?

The table was create as following and there are no triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `prdCodigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prdNome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prdCompra` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `prdVenda` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `prdEstoque` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prdCodigo`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IX_NomeProdutos` (`prdNome`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Have you tried this in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) and do you get the same error?

Comment: Just did it. No errors at all.

Comment: can you include the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE Produtos" and details of any triggers you might have on this table?

Comment: Actually, there was a trigger causing the problem. Thank you @HorusKol!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. make sure column prdCodigo exist in your table. check spelling as well.